# How to use data from fetch correctly in React document title?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am fetching data from github's api using fetch and would like to use the results in the document title, initially this works in development but on manual page reload I get an error.  How can I correctly insert data.name into the document title?

`react-refresh-runtime.development.js:315 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')`

```
 useEffect( () => {
    if ( !login ) return;
    setLoading( true );
    fetch( `https://api.github.com/users/${login}` )
        .then( ( response ) => response.json() )
        .then( setData )
        .then( setLoading( false ) )
        .catch( setError )

}, [login] );

useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `Congratulations ${data.name}'s on Learning React`;

}, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [react-helmet Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet), this is a must famous library to manipulate head tags of your document!

Note: the error in your console occured because your state `data` is not an object, and you are trying get the key `name`.

This is the same of:

```
null.name
```

Note that, `null` is the first value of your state, and to get the `name` of `null` is not possible!